# What is an Adjacent Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it an Adjacent Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is an Adjacent Word™.

The sentences are for context only, and do not affect whether a word is an Adjacent Word™. Also, neither font nor case matters in determining the property.

> 1. ( **Additionally / Furthermore** ), we now have a dog!
> 2. He is concerned about ( **overfishing / overharvesting** ) the oceans.
> 3. She prefers to use ( **margarine / shortening** ) in her cookies.
> 4. She saved it in a new Excel ( **workbook / worksheet** ).
> 5. He loved the ( **ancient / prehistoric** ) buildings.
> 6. They ( **thawed / unfroze** ) their TV dinners.
> 7. They offered the most ( **comprehensive / expansive** ) news coverage.
> 8. They saw that the danger was ( **avoidable / preventable** ).
> 9. They committed an ( **unforgivable / unpardonable** ) sin.
> 10. She just bought her first ( **condominium / townhouse** ).
> 11. The most difficult verbs to learn are ( **irregulars / reflexives** ).

**What makes a word an Adjacent Word™?**

<sub>**Bonus**: If you have solved one of my [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) or [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22versatile%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles before (Deusovi, Rodolvertice, CodeNewbie, xnor, Sean, glibdud, f", dperry), and you solve this one, you will be the first person to solve more than one of these types of puzzles of mine, and you will receive 100 rep points from me, on top of any other points that this puzzle might give (i.e. It might also have a regular bounty on it *if it lasts long enough*.)</sub>

Comment: I really enjoy these, even though I can never solve them

Comment: @warspyking Thanks. Stay positive. You could very well get this one!

Comment: Haha, I doubt it. :P

Comment: There needs to be a tag for JLee's puzzles, [tag:jlee], so we can get a feed...

Comment: I'm so puzzled how you can come up with such things. How do you possibly find that many words that work out?!  I'm amazed!

Comment: @Maverick283 It's not too difficult, just takes some creativity and plenty of time, and some knowledge of how to query a database table that holds a huge list of words. Without database queries, most of the Phrase™ puzzles wouldn't exist.

Comment: I was gonna ask if you use an algorithm that finds these words for you or if you come up with them off the top of your head. I'm still very impressed though, keep it up!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An adjacent word is a word which:

> Can have, from its letters, two different numbers built which are adjacent integers.

Explanation:

> Additionally/Furthermore: From the letters in "furthermore" one may build both "three" and "four", adjacent integers. This cannot be done with "additionally".
>  Overfishing/Overharvesting: From the letters in "overharvesting" one may build "seven" and "eight". Can't be done with "overfishing", which only permits "one" and "five".
>  Margarine/Shortening: From "shortening" one may build "nine" and "ten".
>  Workbook/Worksheet: "worksheet" builds "two" and "three"
>  Ancient/Prehistoric: "ancient" builds "nine" and "ten"
>  Thawed/Unfroze: "unfroze" builds "zero" and "one"
>  Comprehensive/Expansive: "expansive" builds "six" and "seven"
>  Avoidable/Preventable: "preventable" builds "ten" and "eleven"
>  Unforgivable/Unpardonable: "unforgivable" builds "four" and "five"
>  Condominium/Townhouse: "townhouse" builds "one" and "two"
>  Irregulars/Reflexives: "reflexives" builds "five" and "six"

Comment: didn't see this one before I posted, but I'll leave mine mostly as I already typed out all the words.

Answer (score 11):

> It contains the letters of a number written out.

This answer is incomplete. See [commando's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18633/4551).

Comment: these puzzles have a funny way of inspiring first answers that are on the right general track, which lead to someone else posting the correct answer, and the people who got the largest percentage of the puzzle many times don't get the accepted final answer.

Answer (score 7):

Credit goes to xnor for finding the main part of this, but:

> the adjacent numbers contain TWO consecutive numbers spelled out: 
>   Furthermore -> Three, Four 
>   Overharvesting -> Seven, Eight 
>   Shortening -> Eight, Nine 
>   Worksheet -> Two, Three 
>  Ancient -> Nine, Ten 
>  Unfroze -> Zero, One 
>  Expansive -> Six, Seven 
>  Preventable -> Ten, Eleven 
>  
>  Unforgivable -> Four, Five 
>  Townhouse -> One, Two 
>  
>  Reflexives -> Five, Six

Comment: overharvesting should be seven, eight , otherwise you reuse a same letter for the same number...

Comment: Good point.  edited.